# Why is this callback function not working?

Tags: php, arrays, object, callback, comparison

I have the following code:

```
public function compareObjects($object1, $object2){
    return $object1->id - $objects2->id
}

$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'compareObjects');
```

but it keeps saying that the compare method doesn't exist or is an invalid function name....

I thought I did this right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method of an instantiated object is passed as an array containing an object at index 0 and the method name at index 1.

```
// Functions
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'compareObjects');

// Object methods 
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, array($this, 'compareObjects'));
// -OR-
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, array($my_obj, 'compareObjects'));


// Static class methods
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, 'some_class::compareObjects'); // PHP 5.2.3+
```

**[PHP: Callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php)**

Answer (score 1):

It's looking for a pure function, not a class method. You need to use `$this`, as with any call to a class method.

You need to do this...

```
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, array($this, 'compareObjects'));
```

And likewise, if you're using it from outside of your class, you need to use it like this...

```
$objRandom = new Whatever;
// do some fancy PHP stuff, or not
$diff = array_udiff($array1, $array2, array($objRandom, 'compareObjects'));
```

This is pretty much how to use any PHP function with a callback function/method.